# Small XCode Bug where No Output is Shown

Tags: macos, xcode

I've recently begun to learn how to program in C, and have been using the application XCode (ver 7.2) to do so. For the most part, it's been working very well, but I've recently come across a problem:

Whenever I run the main.c file, a popup showing me that the "Build Succeeded," but there is no output shown in the console. Even worse, when I activate the console and run it, the console just goes hides and does not show any output... I've tried looking, but it doesn't seem like this issue is too common... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the top bar:
view->debug area->activate console

Comment: I've tried doing that... But whenever I run the code, the console just goes down and "hides" without any output being shown...